# Sort quiz results by country

Tags: google-forms, google-form-quiz

I've created a quiz in Google Forms. In the "Answers" section, I can see the average Points reached, but I also have a drop-down Country list in the form. Is it possible to sort the average Points reached for every Country?
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

The answer summary page on Google Forms can't be customized. One alternative is to send the responses to a Google Spreadsheet and summarize the response there according to your needs.